# VSTS Create Area Path with WorkItemClassificationNode

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using the VSTS .NET client libraries and I'm trying to create an area path. I already have a `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient`. On this client I can create an area path with the `CreateOrUpdateClassificationNodeAsync` Method. But I can't set the parent of the area path.

```
        var node = new WorkItemClassificationNode();
        node.StructureType = TreeNodeStructureType.Area;
        node.Name = "Test";
        var result = await this.Client.CreateOrUpdateClassificationNodeAsync(node, "Team-Project", TreeStructureGroup.Areas);
```

How can I set the parent of the area path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost got it right. To create a area at a certain path, use the following code:

```
var node = new WorkItemClassificationNode();
node.StructureType = TreeNodeStructureType.Area;
node.Name = “Name”;
var result = this.Client.CreateOrUpdateClassificationNodeAsync(
         node,
         "Project",
          TreeStructureGroup.Areas,
          "Path/to/parent/node/");
```

The important parameter is the path specifying the parent of the new node.

Comment: The iteration path is just / for the root. If you retrieve classification nodes, the path has `\\Project\\Iterations` which is implied when using `CreateOrUpdateClassificationNodeAsync`

Answer (score 1):

Shai has a create set of articles on the TFS SDK. This article shows how you can interact with classification nodes: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/01/30/tfs-api-part-10-add-areaiteration-programmatically/

Comment: Yes, but he used the ICommonStructureService, which I don't have in the VSTS .NET client libraries.